# Installing F-Prot

Tags: installation, package-management

I downloaded the free-edition of F-Prot Anti-Virus for Linux. I am new to Linux and not following how to initiate the installation process. I have extracted the F-Prot files in a folder on my desktop.

There is one file with the name: `install-f-prot.pl`. It is a perl file.

It is giving below mentioned error when I try to run the above perl file:

Failed to create symbolic link `/etc/f-prot.conf -> /home/rp/Desktop/f-prot/f-prot.conf: Permission denied`

Comment: yes it is a perl file. Just run as `perl filename.pl` or chmod it to be executable and run it.

Comment: It is due to permission run as `sudo perl filename.pl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the installation of non-free applications we prefer using the directory `/opt/<nameofapp>/` rather than a directory on your desktop. Using specific paths makes system administration easy.

After having extracted/copied your installation files to `/opt/f-prot/` f-prot will then be installed by the following commands (in a terminal):

```
cd /opt/f-prot/ # our path to installation files
sudo ./install-f-prot.pl # we need to be root
```

For security reasons it is advisable that all files are owned by root. This will make it hard if impossible for malware to gain access to these files:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /opt/f-prot
```

---

An open source alternative to F-Prot is [ClamAV](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/maverick/clamav).

Comment: You can also shorten it to `sudo chown -R root: /opt/f-prot`